# Find Fuji Xerox Printer Mac Address

Tags: printer

If using arp method to trace back MAC address from IP address does not work:

When IP address is known, how to get MAC address of Fuji Xerox Printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Logon to web interface of the printer
   (Using default password)
2. Under Properties Tab:
   Connectivity -> Physical Connections ->
   Ethernet

Answer (score 0):

You can scan your network using the following by downloading it:

[IP-Scanner](http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/)